# How to change styling of a link which is leads to the page that is currently open? CSS HTML Bootrap Pinegrow

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do something very simple... I want links with the class of PAGE-MENU-LINK to be always black which I succeeded in doing. I also want the link which leads to the page on which it is being viewed on to have a line through the middle. In this part, I partially succeeded... The link only has a line through it while I hold down the mouse over it. I want the link to have a line through the middle of it when you hold the button down, and after you click on the page... I would prefer to stick to just CSS and HTML and possibly Javascript... Please not PHP...

**a.PAGE-MENU-LINK:current** does not work the way I thought it would... I am using Pinegrow with Bootstrap

Here is my **style.css**

```
a.PAGE-MENU-LINK:active {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    //color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

a.PAGE-MENU-LINK:current {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    //color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

a.PAGE-MENU-LINK {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<a href="about.html" class="ACTIVE-MENU-LINK PAGE-MENU-LINK">ABOUT</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: [`:visisted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) sounds close to what you want.

Comment: :visited is close to what I need. It changes rules for URLs that are visited previously. So If visited 10 links previously all of them would have had the line through them. I just want only  the link pointing to the current page that is displaying this link have the line go through it. (maximum possible of 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pseudo selector :local-link should do the trick BUT it doesn’t seem to be supported in Chrome (and possibly other major browsers): :local-link - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN

Can do this with JavaScript code, for example, by adding a special class to all local links and then using that class in the selector:

```
<script>
    // add to the end of the document
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href]');
    var page_url = window.location.href.split(/[\?\#]/)[0];
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if(links[i].href.startsWith(page_url)) {
            links[i].classList.add('local-link');
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
   a.local-link { ... }
</style>
```